# Typescript function overloading doesn't work

Tags: typescript, function, overloading

The error is

```
Type '(str: string, convert?: unknown) => { result: number; } | { result: string; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
  Type '{ result: number; } | { result: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ result: string; }'.
    Type '{ result: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ result: string; }'.
      Types of property 'result' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

```
interface X {
    (str: string): {
        result: string
    }
    (str: string, convert: true): {
        result: number
    }
}

const func: X = (str, convert = false) => {
    if (convert) return {
        result: parseInt(str, 10)
    }

    return {
        result: str
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4Chm+QCgGcwoAuZYqUAcwEpzs8nkoJCBXAGzHMppzwBfAbiIleJGgBpkCAPYgAbtB7IS7CPUwjmrDt3Ih2AWwBG0HcOFZ5IYshjsQCcugC8BSjNvKoYZB7wnISaAQB82kzAMAQ+KrQsEGDsUCCRzLh6XKoADnBQIQCS4GJQMgCMAAy0llg6rMmp6RlZBhQktYJAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloads are just function signatures above the concrete implementation. These are syntactic sugars to allow typing of a function that has dynamic arguments.

In JavaScript a function can be written to accept a parameter of mixed types. TypeScript overloads allow statically typing of these dynamic uses of JavaScript functions.

```
function x(str: string): string;
function x(str: string, convert: true): number;
function x(str: string, convert?: boolean) {
  if (convert) {
    return parseInt(str, 10);
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you use with arrow function?

Comment: Unfortunately not. While the function keyword can be used to declare overload signatures; var, let and const can only be used to declare variables and not overload signatures.

Comment: Thanks, I can use normal function. I have found the issue in typescript github https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669.